# Mac port issue with Nginx and Tomcat

Tags: macos, tomcat, nginx, firewall, firewall-access

Configured Nginx to interact with Tomcat on port 9090 on mac.

This configuration works when querying on localhost. Fails to work when connecting from outside, until firewall is disabled.

I have firewall configuration to something like below for forwarding to port 8080 and 8443

```
sudo ipfw add 100 fwd 127.0.0.1,8080 tcp from any to me 80
sudo ipfw add 110 fwd 127.0.0.1,8443 tcp from any to me 443
```

**Request domain.com --> 443 --> nginx on 8443 --> Tomcat 9090**

Side note:

domain.com --> 80 --> re-directs to 443 and then to nginx on 8443 --> Tomcat 9090

**iOS Firewall IPFW** sends everything from **80** to **8080** and **443** to **8443**

**Nginx** is running on **8080** and **8443**

**Nginx** redirects everything from **8080** to **8443**. Nginx on 8443 communicates with Tomcat over 9090.

**Tomcat** is on **9090**

**Router** is configured to allow access on Port **80** and **443**,

So the question, what do I need to change on mac to unblock firewall for a successful 
response.

Comment: Looks to be that you have mentioned Tomcat port as 8080 & 9090. Can you help to identify which is the correct one or that's the cause itself.

Comment: Added more details about configuration; Tomcat is on 9090